# Is there a way to see all of my questions from all sites?

Tags: support, questions, profile-page

I know I can see all of my questions *on a particular site*, but is there a way to see all of my questions **on all sites**? I go to my Stack Exchange profile and there is no Questions tab. Also the `user:me is:question` search doesn't work on the Stack Exchange site, only on particular sites.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/users/3146843/jono?tab=activity

Comment: I did search for an answer to this. I found similar questions with answers, but they all had to do with finding this information on specific sites rather than on all sites together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at all your questions across the SE sites through this link [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/3146843/jono?tab=activity). Select the posts tab. You would get a list of both your questions and answers.

> [image]

Comment: As also pointed out in the duplicates: This only shows you a very limited amount of recent posts. :( unfortunately no easy way to see all of them seems to exist.